# The dimension of the eigenvector space of irreducible matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a irreducible matrix and all the eigenvlaues of $A$ be  positive. Is it true that the eigenvectors of $A$ can span the $R^n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED] They may or may not span it.  For example,

$$ \pmatrix{1 & t\cr 3 & 4\cr} $$
is irreducible for $t \ne 0$, has two distinct positive eigenvalues with eigenvectors spanning $\mathbb R^2$ if $4/3 > t > -3/4$,
but if $t = -3/4$ there is only the one eigenvalue $5/2$ with a one-dimensional eigenspace.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks for your help!

Comment: What about matrices with non-negative entries? Cuz of Perron-Frobenius and stuff?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your calculation. At t=-9/8, the eigenvalues are distinct. It should be -3/4.

Comment: Oops, yes.  Editing.

Comment: For an example with positive entries, try $$ \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 2\cr 2 & 2 & 3\cr 3 & 3 & 5\cr}$$ which has eigenvalues $8$ and $0$, where $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric multiplicity $1$.