# The dimension of the eigenvector space of non-negative irreducible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808437/the-dimension-of-the-eigenvector-space-of-irreducible-matrix) but with an additional condition that the elements are non-negative.

Let $A$ be an irreducible non-negative matrix. Is it true that the eigenvectors of $A$ can span the $R^n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Random counterexample:
$$
\frac{1}{7}\pmatrix{-1&-1&1\\ -1&2&0\\ -1&-2&-1}
\pmatrix{9&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&0&1}
\pmatrix{-2&-3&-2\\ -1&2&-1\\ 4&-1&-3}
=\frac{1}{7}\pmatrix{19&25&19\\ 24&29&10\\ 8&26&29}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you explain this? Are eigenvectors linearly dependent here?

Comment: @Razor The matrix on the RHS is not diagonalisable. Its Jordan form (the matrix in the middle of the LHS) has a non-trivial Jordan block.

Comment: Hmmmm ok, I'll check what's going wrong. It's just that mathematica is giving some distinct complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix on the RHS.

Comment: @Razor Oh, there were some typos. Fixed now.

Comment: This is a very cool example. Very interesting. Thank you very much.